# Java's static vs Ruby's self

Tags: java, ruby

Is `static` in Java like `self` in Ruby?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Java's `static` and Ruby's `self` have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other.

The Java equivalent to Ruby's `self` is `this`. The Ruby equivalent to Java's `static` does not exist.

Java's `static` means that the method is dispatched statically instead of dynamically. In Ruby, methods are *always* dispatched dynamically. `static` means that the method is not called on any object. In Ruby, methods are *always* called on objects. Since `static` methods in Java aren't associated with any object, they don't have access to any object state. In Ruby, methods *always* have access to the state of their associated instance.

In short, `static` methods aren't really methods *at all*, they are procedures. Ruby doesn't have procedures, it only has (instance) methods.

There *is* no construct in Ruby that would even be remotely equivalent to Java's `static`.

Comment: but you use self to have a static behavior in ruby.

Comment: @vurte: You cannot have static behavior in Ruby. Behavior is *always* contained in methods and methods are *always* dynamic. Period.

Comment: sure ... I used the false words. It's not the same. There is a big part of Ruby developers who did Java before. And what I mean is, that you can mimic that kind of code behavior, where Java developers normally uses the "static" keyword (or a singleton) with the metaclass functionality of ruby plus "self".

Answer (score 2):

### So-called "Class methods" are not static methods.

When you do

```
class MyClass
  def self.do_something
    # Do awesome stuff
  end
end
```

`self` merely refers to `MyClass`. (Do `class MyClass; puts self.inspect; end` if you don't believe me!) You can replace `self` with `MyClass`, or even something that refers to the class MyClass, and you'd have the same result.

You could do

```
class MyClass
end

foo = MyClass

def foo.do_something
  # Do awesome stuff
end
```

and you'll get the same results.

And, you can do the same stuff on something that isn't a class

```
my_string = "HAI WORLD"

def my_string.do_something
  # Yet more awesome stuff
end
```

and you can then call `my_string.do_something`

Would calling `do_something` on `my_string` be a static method?

So `self` doesn't magically make a method static.